# How can I return the data in select option

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue here because when I'm saving my data I can get the value of the option box but upon clicking the edit button its the same.. I want to do is it will become the option box with the value showing first

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/te2wF/32/

Heres my code:

```
function Edit(){
    var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
    var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
    var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
    var tdGender = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
    var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

    tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='"+tdName.html()+"'/>");
    tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtage' value='"+tdAge.html()+"'/>");
    tdGender.html(tdGender.html());
    tdButtons.html("<input type='button' value = 'Save' class='btnSave'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/>");

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
    $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
```

Comment: Have you tried reconstructing the whole `select` structure again?

Comment: You bind those events to functions *inside* `Edit()`. That's a problem, even if it's not *the* problem.

Comment: @JLPop - This is how I'll do it: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/PHj7a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/te2wF/35/)

**Few issues resolved:**

**1.** Updated `Edit` function to provide a select option to edit the selection with last selection selected.

```
function Edit() {
        var par = $(this).parent().parent(); //tr
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdGender = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

        tdName.html("<input type='text' id='txtName' value='" + tdName.html() + "'/>");
        tdAge.html("<input type='text' id='txtage' value='" + tdAge.html() + "'/>");
        if(tdGender.html().toLowerCase() == "female") {
            tdGender.html("<select class='gender'><option></option><option>Male</option><option selected>Female</option></select>");
        } else {
            tdGender.html("<select class='gender'><option></option><option selected >Male</option><option >Female</option></select>");
        }
        tdButtons.html("<input type='button' value = 'Save' class='btnSave'/><input type='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/>");

        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);
        $(".btnEdit").bind("click", Edit);
        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
    };
```

**2.** Your code was not able to find `isNumberKey` function. So, I moved it outside the scope so that its accessible from everywhere.

**3.** In your `Add` function, the `select` markup contained an additionally `>`. Removed it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/te2wF/33/

Main 2 changes are that we're storing the select html in a var:

```
var genderSelectHtml = "<select class='gender'><option></option><option value='Male'>Male</option><option value='Female'>Female</option></select>";
```

And then when editing, this recreates the select:

```
$(genderSelectHtml).val(tdGender.html()).appendTo(tdGender.empty());
```

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia