# Editing of Select option follows the value of the Select option in the first row

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox, html-table

This is a follow up question to this link. [How can I return the data in select option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987265/how-can-i-return-the-data-in-select-option)

I found the answer to that question to be effective. If you try to edit rows one at a time, the program works fine. But then, I tried having the first row on edit mode, and another row on edit. If I change and save the gender from Male to Female, and the first row is still having the value Male, the saved value for the row will still be male. Hope that this doesn't seem so complicated. Here is the fiddle of the answer to the question How can I return the data in select option. http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/te2wF/35/

```
 function Save() {

        var value3 = $(".gender").attr('value');
        var par = $(this).parent().parent();
        var tdName = par.children("td:nth-child(1)");
        var tdAge = par.children("td:nth-child(2)");
        var tdGender = par.children("td:nth-child(3)");
        var tdButtons = par.children("td:nth-child(4)");

        tdName.html(tdName.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdAge.html(tdAge.children("input[type=text]").val());
        tdGender.html(value3);
        tdButtons.html("<input type='button' value='Edit' class='btnEdit'/><input type ='button' value='Delete' class='btnDelete'/>");
        $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);  

        $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);

    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were always reading the value of the first select element with class gender instead of gender in the current row

```
tdGender.html(tdGender.children('select').val());
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N5KQA/)

Note: to get the tr element from an descendant element instead of `$(this).parent().parent()` use `var par = $(this).closest('tr')`